# Different 'RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I am programming a chatbot with 'extended' functionalities, and I keep ending up with this error. I know that many other people have already answered, but my code is entirely different. This started happening when I tried to re-train the model with a new vocabulary. Warning: I found the code online and modified it (the final part, I didn't show that).

I tried changing directory, deleting all the files that he created (the model and the data), deleting the 'model.load("...")' and other things, and I am really desperate.

Some other info:

- I use Conda Virtual Env Python 3.6
- I work on the C drive but I use another hard disk to store things
- Some of the imported modules needs to be downloaded with pip

This is part of the code:

```py
# coding: utf-8

import time, pickle, tflearn, nltk, tensorflow, json, random, numpy, os, platform, sys, pyttsx3, speech_recognition, winsound, webbrowser
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

file = open("configuration.settings", "r", encoding='utf-8')
leggi = file.readlines()
file.close()

def cleaner():
    try:
        if platform.system().lower() == "linux" or platform.system().lower() == "darwin":
            os.system("clear")
        elif platform.system().lower() == "windows":
            os.system("cls")
    except:
        pass

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])
            if intent["tag"] not in labels:
                labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))
    labels = sorted(labels)
    training = []
    output = []
    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []
        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]
        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)
        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1
        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)

    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("cbot.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1500, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("cbot.tflearn")

def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]
    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1
    return numpy.array(bag)

### OTHER CODE ###
[...]
```

And this is the complete traceback:

```py
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
---------------------------------
Run id: OK6TM7
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
---------------------------------
Training samples: 57
Validation samples: 0
--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [8,15] rhs shape= [8,12]
         [[{{node save_1/Assign_16}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1286, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [8,15] rhs shape= [8,12]
         [[node save_1/Assign_16 (defined at S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:147) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node save_1/Assign_16:
 FullyConnected_2/W (defined at S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\variables.py:65)

Original stack trace for 'save_1/Assign_16':
  File "D:\\cbot-tts_stt.py", line 94, in <module>
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 65, in __init__
    best_val_accuracy=best_val_accuracy)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 147, in __init__
    allow_empty=True)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 825, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 837, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 875, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 508, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 350, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(saveable_tensors, shapes))
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py", line 72, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 227, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 69, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\cbot-tts_stt.py", line 97, in <module>
    model.load("cbot.tflearn")
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 308, in load
    self.trainer.restore(model_file, weights_only, **optargs)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 490, in restore
    self.restorer.restore(self.session, model_file)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1322, in restore
    err, "a mismatch between the current graph and the graph")
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [8,15] rhs shape= [8,12]
         [[node save_1/Assign_16 (defined at S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:147) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node save_1/Assign_16:
 FullyConnected_2/W (defined at S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\variables.py:65)

Original stack trace for 'save_1/Assign_16':
  File "D:\\cbot-tts_stt.py", line 94, in <module>
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 65, in __init__
    best_val_accuracy=best_val_accuracy)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 147, in __init__
    allow_empty=True)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 825, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 837, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 875, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 508, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 350, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(saveable_tensors, shapes))
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py", line 72, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 227, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 69, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\cbot-tts_stt.py", line 99, in <module>
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1500, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 216, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 339, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 816, in _train
    tflearn.is_training(True, session=self.session)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 95, in is_training
    tf.get_collection('is_training_ops')[0].eval(session=session)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 731, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5579, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "S:\WindowsPrograms\Anaconda3\envs\ptg\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1096, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Thank you for reading this, and I am really sorry for some errors in the text.
Thanks for giving me your time!

Comment: @gobrewers14 it was working perfectly yesterday

Comment: @gobrewers14 well, i tried installing the same virual env on my linux and it give me the same error as windows.

Comment: okay so you got the same error on linux w/a venv.  edit your question with the new error. lets debug this thing! :)

Comment: I didn't get your reply, which error are you talking about? The traceback is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: post the MINIMAL about of code that reproduces you error

Comment: @gobrewers14 I checked the code and the one that i posted is the minimal in order to make it work.

Comment: @gobrewers14 for the record, Conda + Windows works just fine. This error has nothing to do with the environment used and actually reading the error message would have given you a very strong hint that the problem was neither in TF nor in Conda.

Comment: @GPhilo :thumbs-ups:

Answer (score 0):

The Traceback has all the information you need, but you need to read it from the top to bottom because the lowest reported error is not always the actual error message.

> Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [8,15] rhs shape= [8,12]

and further down:

> Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint.

You're running the model in a "dirty" folder (it contains results from previous attempts with a different model). Delete your old checkpoints or change training directory.

Comment: lets not reward posts like this.  we need minimal reproducibles examples. code dumps with errors help no one.

Comment: I don't see how answering is "rewarding" the post. The information provided was enough to pinpoint the problem exactly, so I answer. The question is badly formed, so it gets downvoted, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't receive an answer if it is answerable.

Comment: fair enough.  but encouraging posts that generalize to the 
 common populace certainly make this site more efficient.

Comment: @GPhilo I alredy tried deleting all the files that he create after the training (including old checkpoints) and changing the training directory